# Passive of verb "let" : with or without "to"

Tags: passive-voice, infinitives

Page 64 of the fourth edition of Practical English Usage reads

> Verbs which can be followed, in active structures, by object +
> infinitive without  to, use to-infinitives in passive structures.
> Compare:
>
> - I *saw* him come out of the house.
> - He was *seen* **to** come out of the house.
> - They *made* him tell them everything.
> - He was *made* **to** tell them everything.
> - They *helped* him (to) get out of the country.
> - He was *helped* **to** get out of the country.

However, the passive of ***let** go* (dismiss) does not use infivitive-to.
Therefore, I'd like to know why this is so.

Secondly, I'd like to know the correct passive for the phrase *let pass*, as in *[Senator McCracken never **let** an opportunity **pass** for bringing up his service record.](https://www.google.es/books/edition/We_Were_Warriors_Once/ldPRj3HiFBgC?hl=es&gbpv=1&dq=let%20the%20opportunity%20pass&pg=PA200&printsec=frontcover)*

Contradicting examples can be found in Google Books

[An attempt was made to stop a Swedish ship, but she refused to halt, and **was let pass**](https://www.google.es/books/edition/The_Soviets_Greatest_Gambit/70I6EAAAQBAJ?hl=es&gbpv=1&dq=%22was%20let%20pass%22&pg=PA194&printsec=frontcover)

[The guests **were let to pass** forward](https://www.google.es/books/edition/The_Road_Leading_to_Hell/AdxQAAAAQBAJ?hl=es&gbpv=1&dq=%22were%20let%20to%20pass%22&pg=PA53&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: What's the example sentence you're asking about? _Let go_ is an idiom, not a verb. And it has a number of meanings and constructions. Don't describe it; give examples, please.

Comment: Might help to understand that '*let*' often means '*allow*' or '*permit*' - *Let him go*'// allow/permit him to go

Comment: You're certainly correct about "let [object] go": "They let him go." -> "He was let go." However, I can't think of any valid cases when another verb (besides "go") is used, leading me to suspect that this idiomatic. Can you come up with examples besides "let [object] go"?

Comment: "Let" as used in "let pass" (like "allow" but with a bare infinitive rather than a to-infinitive) does not have a passive voice equivalent.

Comment: "They **let him** tell them everything". In the passive is: **He was allowed [by someone] to tell them everything**. When the verb let is used for the verb allow, the passive is allow. let cannot be passivized.

Comment: I believe "let go" as in "to fire an employee" can be passivized, though: "he was let go during the layoffs."

Comment: @alphabet let go does not collocate with his other verbs.

Comment: [_An attempt was made to stop a Swedish ship, but she refused to halt, and **was let pass**_](https://www.google.es/books/edition/The_Soviets_Greatest_Gambit/70I6EAAAQBAJ?hl=es&gbpv=1&dq=%22was%20let%20pass%22&pg=PA194&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: [_The guests **were let to pass** forward_](https://www.google.es/books/edition/The_Road_Leading_to_Hell/AdxQAAAAQBAJ?hl=es&gbpv=1&dq=%22were%20let%20to%20pass%22&pg=PA53&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: To all and singular: please stop discussing potential answers in comments and write an answer instead. Thank you.

Comment: I created a room in chat. I posted a proposed answer but would like it reviewed before posting it.

Comment: @GJC What a hoot. Look at the dedication, look at the name of the author's brother, look at any paragraph. The English is riddled with oddities. The author is most like Russian, which can also be deduced from the determiner mistakes...

Answer (score 3):

In the case of *let go*, ***go*** is a particle (a one-word non-expandable phrase functioning as complement to the verb) and hence does not allow  ***to***. Same goes for ***slip*** in *let slip*. Compare the acceptability of:

> He was let **go** on Monday. [particle]
>
> He was let **go to the concert** **on Monda**y. [plain infinitival]
>
> It was let **slip** that there would be another tour. [particle]
>
> It was let **slip** **down the hill**. [plain infinitival]

Most attempts at using ***let*** in the passive with a plain infinitival complement come off as questionable, almost colloquial.

> this was so even when you were practically sure you would be **let
> stay on** for another ride but of course it was much more so when you
> knew that it was absolutely the last ride and that no amount of
> begging or arguing would make any difference (Harpers 2007)
>
> They forgot all about my bedtime and I was **let stay up** though my eyes
> felt full of sand. (Pigeons, Michael McLaverty, 1936)

Perhaps then, of the examples given in the question, when the writer had a single word complement of ***let***, there was no ***to*** included, this case being more similar to the particle construction ***let go***; but, when there was a multi-word complement, the ***to*** was added possibly to increase acceptability or abide by some rule similar to the one mentioned.

> An attempt was made to stop a Swedish ship, but she refused to halt,
> and was let **pass**.   [particle-like]
>
> The guests were let **to pass forward**.   [infinitival clause as
> complement]

*To*-infinitivals as complements of passive ***let*** are few and far between in modern day English publications (21st  Century), thought they do seem to have had some traction in the past.

> But she saw that Miss Henderson spoke only truth in declaring it was
> the best way to take her out of her worries; she read Nurse Sampson's
> look, and saw that she, at any rate, was quite resolved her patient
> should not be **let to dwell longer on any painful or apprehensive
> thought**, and she put off all her own anxious questionings, till she
> should see the nurse alone, and said, in a low tone -- yes, Paul
> Rushleigh had been there. (Culm Rock, 1867)
>
> this instance i choose, the condition of those theban kings being the
> neerest to this of rollo and otto: for they also were equally kings,
> could not agree, kill'd each other: that we might not suspect that the
> dissention between them rose from any malice of their own, we are
> **let** **to** **know**, **that the gods owe a vengeance to thebes, which is now ripe, and ready to fall upon them, for a crime of their founder**
> **cadmus** (Rymer, Thomas, 1641-1713)

Comment: https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Best_British_Short_Stories_and_the_Y/LYcUAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22I%20was%20let%20stay%20up%22%20%20%22my%20eyes%22 seems the story was printed in 1936

Comment: @Mari-LouA Quite correct. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: You needn't have deleted the quotation, even if it was written nearly 90 years ago.